# Doubt about how "ohne" influences sentence meaning

Tags: translation, word-usage

Studying on Duolingo, I am trying to translate this sentence here:

> Die ersten Kakaobohnen brachte Christoph Kolumbus aus Amerika mit, **ohne dass man zu dieser Zeit etwas damit anfangen konnte**.

I get the first part, but I am struggling with the bold part. How does *ohne* influence the sentence meaning? I thought *ohne dass* [could be taken as a but](http://www.dict.cc/?s=ohne+dass), however "but at that time they could do something with that" doesn't make much sense when you read everything.

Comment: You may want to compare the [**conjunction** "without"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/without).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Literally *ohne* is *without*, and that is the negation you missed.

Therefore

> but at that time they could do something with that (!)

should really be

> but at that time they could not do something with that.

or

> without them being able to do something with it.

If the subject matches the complement after *ohne*, the *dass* particle could be dropped. But that needs a *zu* particle:

> Er fuhr ab, **ohne** tschüss **zu** sagen.

Comment: It is worth noting, that you also can use "ohne" with an Infinitiv+zu construction, if the subjects match: **Er raste über die Autobahn, *ohne* sich Gedanken über die Sicherheit *zu machen*.**

Comment: Po polsku, @c.p.? Nie ma za co!

Answer (score 3):

You could see it as a kind of **but**.
ohne means without.

> Die ersten Kakaobohnen brachte Christoph Kolumbus aus Amerika mit,
>   aber zu dieser Zeit konnte man damit nichts anfangen.

Comment: So *ohne dass* can act as a *but* and negate the meaning of the remaining sentence?

Comment: @rockleegustavo Yes