# Why is this "ohne dass"?

Tags: conjunction

This phrase is taken from Donna Leon's Acqua Alt:

> noch konnte ein Detektiv, der nicht selbst in der Gegend wohnte, sich länger als eine halbe Stunde dort aufhalten, **ohne dass** in der Questura angerufen und seine verdächtige Anwesenheit gemeldet wurde.

I would like to understand why this phrase contains "ohne dass" and not simply "ohne"?

Comment: Does [this](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/satzverbindung-modal-ohne-dass-ohne/)(German) help a bit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doubt about how "ohne" influences sentence meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24036/doubt-about-how-ohne-influences-sentence-meaning)

Comment: I did not find "Doubt about how "ohne" influences sentence meaning" helpful, but the Deutsche Grammatik 2.0 reference made it perfectly clear. Thank you.

Comment: "niemals <A>, ohne dass <B>" == "Whenever <A>, <B>".

Comment: Instructive examples here: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/54292/35111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ohne** without **dass** is not a conjunction and therefore it cannot introduce a subclause. That's why omitting *dass* makes the sentence ungrammatical.

However, **ohne** can be used with an infinitive construction. But this works only if the main clause and the infinitive construction have the same subject. For example:

> Er kann sich nicht länger als eine halbe Stunde dort aufhalten, ohne aufzufallen.